# Python: open protected password sqlite database file

Tags: python, database, encryption, sqlite, passwords

Like the title says I got an .db file which I had encrypted with SQLiteBrowser
by entering a password.
The password is called "test"

Now I am using Python 3.4 and I want to read from the .db file

this is what I have so far:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('TEST.db')
c = conn.cursor()
for row in c.execute('SELECT value FROM data'):
    row = str(row)
    print(row)
```

Now the problem is that I do not know how to enter the password to open the file within python.

The following error I get when executing the code above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/PROJECT GATE/HOP.py", line 5, in <module>
    for row in c.execute('SELECT naam FROM gegeven'):
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

So my question how can I enter the password within python to read from the .db file?

Comment: nobody knows the answer how to do this?